# Как сделать так чтоб в Contact Form 7 (плагин WordPress) reCAPTHCA выводилась не всегда, а только по определённым условиям?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, recaptcha, contact-form7

Как сделать так чтоб в Contact Form 7 (плагин WordPress) reCAPTHCA выводилась не всегда, а только по определённым условиям?

Comment: При каких обстоятельствах? Конкретизировать можно?

Comment: Лучше  снести эту рекпчу для всех условий. Сайт с рекапчей = вебмастер-неуч/ленив (/у заказчика нет денег на нормального). Только гуглу она нужна для сбора перс данных и своих экскрементах .